# How do I enter twrp recovery?

Tags: recovery-mode, htc-one-xl, twrp

I unlocked (not rooted) my HTC One XL using official HTC method. Then I install goomanger and installed latest open recovery script TWRP 2.3.0.0 evita. goomanager said that it was installed. Then I tried to boot into recovery from goomanger (there was a note that root access will be acquired and if this doesn't happen I have to go to recovery manually). Nothing happened I was still in goomanager.

From  [TWRP website](http://teamw.in/project/twrp2/99) -->`You must be S-OFF or have taken HTC's unlock to use a recovery on your device!`

So I booted into fastboot and then selected recovery and pressed power button. See the screenshot for what happened. I got the 'briliant' screen then black screen with mobile and green something above it and then black screen with mobile and red triangle. The red one stays there for 2-3 minutes and then mobile restarts into normal mode.

[image]

I want to run twrp to install cm10

Comment: *(not rooted)* yet, *there was a note that root access will be acquired and if this doesn't happen I have to go to recovery manually* - Have you actually tried rooting first before doing that?

Comment: From TWRP website: `You must be S-OFF or have taken HTC's unlock to use a recovery on your device!` - I did the second one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Installing a recovery and flashing your rom

1. Download your recovery.img or wahtever the name is to your fastboot folder.
2. adb reboot bootloader
3. fastboot flash recovery recovery.img
4. fastboot reboot recovery
5. Now use your recovery to flash your rom.

At this point you may not be able boot into your rom if you do not have S-OFF.But give it a try. If it works then forget the next few lines.

1. Copy the boot.img file from inside your rom and copy it to your fasboot folder.
2. adb reboot bootloader
3. fastboot flash boot boot.img.

Now you can reboot to boot into your rom.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138160/discussion-on-answer-by-varunyellina-how-do-i-enter-twrp-recovery).